# Garbled output when send ascii string from Android to Arduino using socket

Tags: android, sockets, arduino

I am trying to send data from Android to an Arduino with a Wifi shield.

The data I'm receiving at the Arduino however is not the same as I am sending from Android. For example when I send the character 'A' (ASCII 65), what I receive at the Arduino is an underscore '_' (ASCII 95).

The following list shows some examples of what I'm sending from Android and how it maps to what I'm receiving in Arduino. Perhaps someone can see what is going on here??

```
Sent From Android         || Received in Arduino
----------------------------------------------------
Symbol | Dec | Bin        || Symbol | Dec | Bin
----------------------------------------------------
A      | 65  | 01000001   || _      | 95  | 01011111
B      | 66  | 01000010   || /      | 47  | 00101111
C      | 67  | 01000011   || ^      | 94  | 01011110
D      | 68  | 01000100   || ETB    | 23  | 00010111
E      | 69  | 01000101   || ]      | 93  | 01011101
F      | 70  | 01000110   || .      | 46  | 00101110
G      | 71  | 01000111   || \      | 92  | 01011100
H      | 72  | 01001000   || VT     | 11  | 00001011
I      | 73  | 01001001   || [      | 91  | 01011011
J      | 74  | 01001010   || -      | 45  | 00101101
K      | 75  | 01001011   || Z      | 90  | 01011010
```

I notice a couple of patterns forming here.

*Looking at each of the odd numbered decimal sent values:*

```
65 -> 95
67 -> 94
69 -> 93
71 -> 92
73 -> 91
75 -> 90
```

*Looking at every other even numbered decimal sent value:*

```
66 -> 47
70 -> 46
74 -> 45
```

I have run this at a baud of 57600, and have also tried slowing it right down to 9600 with identical results.

The code I've used for sending and receiving is below:

***Sending from Android***

```
DataOutputStream outStream;

try {
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.16.254", 8080);
    outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    outStream.write(sendString.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
    socket.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***Receiving in Arduino***

```
if(Serial.available()) {
    NowMS = millis();

    // Loop to read data from the Serial buffer into our String
    while(true) {

      // Loop until we have some data or we time out
      while(Serial.available() == false) {
        if (millis() > NowMS + TimeoutMS) {
          // we haven't received any more data for a while.
          timed_out = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (timed_out) {
        inputString = "";
        break;
      }

      // We haven't timed out and we have serial data available, so add the next char to our String
      int incomingByte = Serial.read();
      char receivedChar = (char)incomingByte;
      Serial.print("Received Char: ");
      Serial.print(receivedChar);
      Serial.print(" [");
      Serial.print(incomingByte);
      Serial.println("]");

      inputString += receivedChar;

      if (inputString.endsWith("=end")) {
        // we've reached the end of the request
        has_request = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (has_request) {
      Serial.print("Received String: ");
      Serial.println(inputString);
      has_request = false;
      inputString = "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Turns out it was a hardware problem with the Arduino board.